# Better about page example questions/answers/comments

Tags: feature-request

I [recently posted on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169946/197656) about the example questions, answers, and comments found on various site's about pages, and [was told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169950/197656) that although some sites have auto-system-picked examples, the mods of each site can change the example questions.

Currently, the following answer is featured on the Code Golf about page:

[image: How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies]

Although I don't frequent Code Golf, I have no doubt that unicorns are as much a part of the culture here at Code Golf as they are at MSO, but I think it would be best to show a different question on the about page, since elsewhere on the about page it gives these guidelines for questions:

[image: Don't ask about... Anything that's not a programming puzzle or code golf]

I don't visit Code Golf often (I'm usually on SO), so maybe I'm missing something, but I think better examples could be chosen.

**Would the mods consider manually picking one of the best questions here to put on the about page to help new users better understand the site?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the system is not offering us any to chose from. The [conditions for a question to be a candidate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163948/2509) are such that very few CodeGolf.SE questions are going to qualify.

In particular the requirement for the question to be 400 characters or less and without "crazy" formatting which I suspect includes code-blocks; and to have two answer that are similarly short and simple is a real stinker for us.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. Just thought I'd see if anyone had considered changing it.

Comment: One of the 'tips' questions might qualify, but that'd be less than ideal.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps codegolf needs a more drastic reformatting of the *about* page. For one, it should talk about *challenges* rather than *questions*.

Comment: For that matter, instead of *Ask Question*, we should have *Pose Challenge*.